# Transform html table to image in Python(other solves aren't working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I need to save html table as image(argb, png), but all solves on stackoverflow aren't good for my project, because all of them working with os(cmd) or use api with limited number of uses. I need to save picture infinity number of times and this have to work in Jupiter Notebook.

How I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a browser driver to take a picture of your html.
Generaly you can take a picture of a remote page with pyppeteer :

```
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
async def main():
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://example.com/')
    await page.screenshot({'path': './example.png'})
    await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

And you can also put into the `goto` call directly the content with a data url :

```
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
import base64
async def main():
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('data:text/html,<table><tr><td>Some Cell</td><td>Some Other cell</td></tr></table>')
    await page.screenshot({'path': './screenshot.png'})
    await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

the picture generate by this looks like this :

[image: Table Render]

Ofcourse you need to install `pyppeteer` for that with  in your virtual env:

`$ python -m pip install pyppeteer`

---

The same as above but written into a Jupyter Notebook here : https://gist.github.com/tiberiucorbu/6726e27a736ba7b07e3d0973e905e4ff

Comment: Can i use this in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I'm no Jupyter expert but I got it working. check my updated answer